# Formulário fica em branco depois de apertar um botão, me ajudem!

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-sheets

Sou meio novo programando em HTML, CSS e scripts de modo geral. Entendo quase o básico do funcionamento e eu estou tentando organizar o recebimento de documentos no meu Departamento, havia feito tudo em Access mas infelizmente nem todas as máquinas possuem pacote Office e a implantação foi totalmente um desastre, tentando contornar isso, passei para o Google Sheets já que ele possui uma boa avaliação por parte do mercado.

A ideia inicial era de preencher um formulário e o mesmo inserir tudo em uma planilha para posteriormente eu trabalhar com os dados inseridos nesta planilha.

Sendo assim, criei um formulário HTML que permite ser aplicado dentro das planilhas google por meio de script e botões, clicando no botão temos a ativação da função FormDPGT:

```js
function FormDPGT() {
  // Declaração de vars
  var Form = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("cadprocesso");
  var MostrarForm = Form.evaluate();
  
  // Cria e exibe o formulário de Cad. Processo (620x850)
  MostrarForm.setTitle("Cadastro de Tramite Processual").setHeight(620).setWidth(850);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(MostrarForm, "Cadastro de Tramite Processual");
}
```

E a parte responsável pelo formulário em HTML é esta:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>           
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/js/materialize.min.js"></script> 
    <script> $(document).ready(function() {$('select').material_select();}); </script>
    <script language="JavaScript">
      function mascara(t, mask){
        var i = t.value.length;
        var saida = mask.substring(1,0);
        var texto = mask.substring(i);
        
        if (texto.substring(0,1) != saida){ t.value += texto.substring(0,1); }
      }
    </script>
    <subtitle>Inserção de tramite de processos analisados pelos técnicos do DPGT.</subtitle><br><br>
  </head>

  <body>
    <style type="text/css">
      html{overflow-y:auto; overflow-x:hidden;}
    </style>
    <div class="conteiner">
      <form class="col s12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="nprocesso" type="text" autocomplete="off" required>
          <label for="nprocesso">Nº do Processo</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="interessado" type="text" required>
          <label for="interessado">Interessado</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input onkeypress="mascara(this, '##/##/####')" id="data_recebimento" type="text" placeholder="Ex.: dd/mm/aaaa" maxlength="10" autocomplete="off" required>
          <label for="data_recebimento">Data de recebimento</label>
          <span class="helper-text" data-error="wrong" data-success="right">Data de recebimento do processo no DMOP</span>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input onkeypress="mascara(this, '##/##/####')" id="data_analise" type="text" placeholder="Ex.: dd/mm/aaaa" maxlength="10" autocomplete="off" required>
          <label for="data_analise">Data de início da pré-análise</label>
          <span class="helper-text" data-error="wrong" data-success="right">Data de início da pré-análise pelo técn.</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <select id="analista" required>
            <option value="" disabled selected>Responsável pela análise</option>
            <option value="1">Décio Henrique</option>
            <option value="2">Fernanda Moreira</option>
            <option value="3">José Liberato</option>
            <option value="4">Joseleno dos Santos</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <select id="status" required>
            <option value="" disabled selected>Status</option>
            <option value="1">Em Análise</option>
            <option value="2">Fora de Enquadramento</option>
            <option value="3">Deferido</option>
            <option value="4">Indeferido</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <textarea id="situacao" class="materialize-textarea" data-length="120" autocomplete="off" required></textarea>
          <label for="situacao">Situação</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <textarea id="infoauxiliar" class="materialize-textarea" data-length="120" autocomplete="off"></textarea>
          <label for="infoauxiliar">Informações Auxiliares</label>
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <button id="salvar" class="btn waves-effect waves-light">Salvar<i class="material-icons right">send</i></button>
          <button id="limpar" type="reset" class="btn waves-effect waves-light">Limpar<i class="material-icons right">clear_all</i></button>
          <button id="cancelar" type="button" onclick="self.close()" class="btn waves-effect waves-light">Cancelar<i class="material-icons right">cancel</i></button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script>
    
      var CampoProcesso = document.getElementByID("nprocesso");
      var CampoInteressado = document.getElementByID("interessado");
      var CampoDataReceb = document.getElementByID("data_recebimento");
      var CampoDataInic = document.getElementByID("data_analise");
      var CampoAnalista = document.getElementByID("analista");
      var CampoStatus = document.getElementByID("status");
      var CampoSituacao = document.getElementByID("situacao");
      var CampoInfoAux = document.getElementByID("infoauxiliar");
      
      document.getElementByID("salvar").addEventListener("click", Salvar);

      function Salvar(){
        
        var processo = CampoProcesso.value;
        var interessado = CampoInteressado.value;
        var datareceb = CampoDataReceb.value;
        var datainic = CampoDataInic.value;
        var analista = CampoAnalista.value;
        var status = CampoStatus.value;
        var situacao = CampoSituacao.value;
        var infoaux = CampoInfoAux.value;
        var dados = { processo: CampoProcesso.value, interessado: CampoInteressado.value, datareceb: CampoDataReceb.value, datainic: CampoDataInic.value, analista: CampoAnalista.value, status: CampoStatus.value, situacao: CampoSituacao.value, infoaux: CampoInfoAux.value};
        
        google.script.run.RegistrarProcesso(dados);
        
        CampoProcesso.value = "";
        CampoInteressado.value = "";
        CampoDataReceb.value = "";
        CampoDataInic.value = "";
        CampoAnalista.value = "";
        CampoStatus.value = "";
        CampoSituacao.value = "";
        CampoInfoAux.value = "";
        
        M.toast({html: 'Novo tramite cadastrado com sucesso!'});
      }
      
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

A ideia era ao clicar no botão Salvar rodar o script declarado no fim do corpo do código e posteriormente chamar esta função aqui:

```js
function RegistrarEntrada(dados) {
  // Declaração de vars
  var Plan = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("CAD. DPGT 2019");
  var Home = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("INÍCIO");
  
  // Procura a linha para inserir os dados
  Plan.getActiveCell();
  Plan.getRange('A1').activate();
  Plan.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  Plan.getActiveCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
  
  // Insere os dados na linha
  var Linha = Plan.getCurrentCell().getRow();
  Plan.getRange(Linha, 1).setValue([dados.datareceb]);
  Plan.getRange(Linha, 2).setValue([dados.processo]);
  Plan.getRange(Linha, 3).setValue([dados.interessado]);
  Plan.getRange(Linha, 4).setValue([dados.datainic]);
  Plan.getRange(Linha, 5).setValue([dados.analista]);
  Plan.getRange(Linha, 6).setValue([dados.status]);
  Plan.getRange(Linha, 7).setValue([dados.situacao]);
  Plan.getRange(Linha, 8).setValue([dados.infoaux]);
  //Plan.getRange(Linha, 9).setValue([dados.processo]);
  //Plan.getRange(Linha, 10).setValue([dados.processo]);
  
  Home.getRange('A1').activate();
}
```

MAAAAAAAAAAS... Infelizmente ao clicar no botão, o formulário fica em branco e não acontece nada, não salva nada nem nada, só fica o título aparecendo, assim:

[image: Form em branco após o clique no botão Salvar]

Me ajudem, por favor, isso vai melhorar e muito o trabalho de muitos.

Att,

Answer (score 0):

o problema era só o form que havia sido declarado após o container, ele era removido do container após o clique no botão, entretanto, o botão ainda não realiza sua função.

Fiz um novo tópico (inclusive não sabia se pode): [Botão não envia formulário e/ou roda javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/398382/bot%c3%a3o-n%c3%a3o-envia-formul%c3%a1rio-e-ou-roda-javascript)

Mas desde já agradeço aos que prestaram no mínimo a atenção ao tópico, entretanto fica ai a nova dúvida e desafio gerado por este formulário.

Att,