# Botão não envia formulário e/ou roda javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-sheets

Fala, pessoal. Então... Estou com dificuldades em fazer o botão que enviaria um formulário preenchido para uma planilha no Google Sheets e em seguida zeraria os campos, toda a aplicação está rodando no próprio site. Estou utilizando o javascript abaixo de chamada de tela, ação do botão e inserção dos dados do formulário na planilha, respectivamente:

```js
function Formulario() {
  // Declaração de vars
  var Form = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("formulario");
  var MostrarForm = Form.evaluate();

  // Cria e exibe o formulário de Cad. Processo (280x450)
  MostrarForm.setTitle("Cadastro de Processo").setHeight(280).setWidth(450);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(MostrarForm, "Cadastro de Processo");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        var CampoProcesso = document.getElementByID("nprocesso");
        var CampoInteressado = document.getElementByID("interessado");
        
        function Salvar(){
          var processo = CampoProcesso.value;
          var interessado = CampoInteressado.value;
          
          google.script.run.RegistrarProcesso(processo, interessado);
        
          CampoProcesso.value = "";
          CampoInteressado.value = "";
          
          M.toast({html: 'Cadastro realizado com sucesso!'});
        }
      </script>
```

```js
function RegistrarProcesso(processo,interessado) {
  // Declaração de vars
  var Home = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("INÍCIO");
  var Plan = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("LOL");
  
  // Procura a linha para inserir os dados
  Plan.getRange('A1').activate();
  Plan.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  Plan.getActiveCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
  
  // Insere os dados na linha
  var Linha = Plan.getCurrentCell().getRow();
  Plan.getRange(Linha, 1).setValue(processo);
  Plan.getRange(Linha, 2).setValue(interessado);
  
  Home.getRange('A1').activate();
}
```

E o formulário em si:

```html
<!--Criação do formulário-->
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
            <input id="nprocesso" type="text" autocomplete="off">
            <label for="nprocesso">Nº do Processo</label>
          </div>
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <i class="material-icons prefix">phone</i>
            <input id="interessado" type="text" autocomplete="off">
            <label for="interessado">Interessado</label>
          </div>
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <button type="button" onclick="Salvar()" class="btn waves-effect waves-light">Salvar
              <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pelo o que eu vi você não executou nenhuma função que você criou.

Você deu um nome a função, portanto ela só vai executar se for chamada, por exemplo:

```
Formulario(); RegistrarProcesso();
```

Você colocou também a função salvar no `onclick` do `button`, mas você a definiu?